# Does there exist an acyclic graph with at least 3 vertices with all vertices of degree/valence of 2?

Tags: graph-theory

I swear no matter what I do, I can't come up with a graph with 3 vertices or more and vertices has all degree 2 and is non cyclic

Comment: Why do you expect that such a graph exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed infinite graphs, then yes, of course they exist. Every vertex has two edges to new vertices, who each have an edge to a new vertex, who each have an edge...

If you are not allowed infinite graphs, then you are limited to $n$ vertices. Suppose you pick a vertex and an edge, then from that vertex pick a new edge, and so on. Erase all edges thus traversed. Eventually either you have a vertex with an edge in but not out (therefore originally being degree 1, disallowed) or you have a vertex with an edge in, and an edge out to a previously visited vertex.

Since you erased all edges in one path to that vertex by the process above, yet a path still exists, these paths are distinct, therefore they form a cycle in the graph.

If the graph is disconnected, the reasoning applies on each subgraph.

Answer (score 0):

By an acyclic graph I presume you mean a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)), or a forest of disjoint trees. Every tree with at least one edge has a leaf: a vertex of degree $1$.